# scala function for java's node.getTagName

Tags: xml, scala

what is the equivalent in scala of java's node.getTagName?

for instance, if the function "tagName" would exist in scala xml.XML, I'd do as follows:

```
val node = <a><b/><c/></a>
```

node.tagName?  should be "a"

node.head.tagName?  should be "b".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `label`:

```
scala> val a = <a><b/><c/></a>
a: scala.xml.Elem = <a><b></b><c></c></a>

scala> a.label
res0: String = a

scala> a.child.head.label
res1: String = b
```

Comment: Did you mean a.child.head.label?